# Why is my code causing (EDIT:) my page to crash?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to randomly load some images to the page's html divs and my code is sometimes working, like on the first page load, but on maybe the second or third it causes the page to blank out and buffer and crashes the tab. 
Here's a link to the full file (Excluding image srcs):

Here's the full js file:  (be careful because it will crash the tab if you reload it several times)
https://repl.it/GBvG/2

```
var topnum = 7;  //will later be used to represent current index
var rando;    //will later be used as a swap index
var temporary;   //will later be used as a temporary holder so we can swap rando and topnum
var myCard = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
var myArray = [
  'Images/aceheart.png',
  'Images/aceheart.png',
  'Images/kingheart.png',
  'Images/kingheart.png', 
  'Images/queenheart.png',
  'Images/queenheart.png',
  'Images/tenheart.png',
  'Images/tenheart.png'
];

function create(){

     while(topnum > 0){ //loops over all 8 elements
          rando = Math.floor((Math.random() * topnum) + 0);
        //will swap elements as long as the random index we got is not the same as the current index  
        if(myArray[rando] !== myArray[topnum]){ 

          temporary = myArray[topnum];
          myArray[topnum] = myArray[rando]; //randomizes topindex value
          myArray[rando] = temporary;
        topnum--;
        }; // end of if    
      };  //end of while 

    for(var i = 0; i <= 8;i++){
       var imgElement = "<img src='" + myArray[i] + "' alt='test' width='200px' height='275px'/>";
       myCard[i].innerHTML = imgElement;

    }; //end of for loop


}; // end of create
```

I'm almost positive the problem is with this snippet, though I don't know why:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 8;i++){
   var imgElement = "<img src='" + myArray[i] + "' alt='test' width='200px' height='275px'/>";
   myCard[i].innerHTML = imgElement;

}; //end of for loop
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that that code will cause a stack overflow error.

Comment: In your `while` loop, if the `if` condition is false,  toponum will never be reduced.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, your proposal can be the only overflow reason. If I were you, I would promote this comment to an answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes, that was it. My code runs perfectly fine now, thank you

Comment: No worries. Please accept @nem035 answer, which explains where to put `toponum--`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 8 cards but your loop runs 9 iterations.

Change

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 8;i++)
```

To

```
for(var i = 0; i < 8;i++) // use `<` instead of `<=`
```

Also, as Gerardo Furtado mentioned in the comments, you should put `topnum--` outside the `if` in the `while` loop. Otherwise you'll have an infinite loop.

```
while(topnum > 0) {
  rando = Math.floor((Math.random() * topnum) + 0);
  if(myArray[rando] !== myArray[topnum]){ 
    // ...
  }
  topnum--; // <-- move the decrement here
}
```